# Storing an array of hashes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm working on an app in rails and I want to store an ordered array of hashes in ActiveRecord, but it'm running into a snag(s). I want to store a URL, the hash's position in the array, and a few metrics associated with a single keyword.

I've tried to use a has_many/belongs_to association between a keyword/rankings model, and I tried storing the array of hashes in a single cell with serialize, but it's not writing to the db for some reason.

Here's what I want to store:

```
Keyword - [{rank(1), url, metric1, metric2}, {rank(2), url, metric1, metric2},...{rank(n), url, metric1, metric2}]
```

I guess I'm just struggling with the technical implementation; tried two different models with associations, serialize, and so on. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

If its not writing to the DB, make sure that its `attr_accessible` in the first place. Also, make sure that the column of the Array/Hash is of type `:text`.

Comment: The attributes are accessible and it's text field. Could it be something else? Do I only need to serialize one text-field attribute to be able to stores an array of hashes in it? Not sure why it wouldn't be working then...

Comment: Text field as in the database type must be :text as opposed to :string. After that, you can store your array of hashes.